# Magic mouse 2 always on?

Tags: mouse

So I just bought a new magic mouse 2 and I noticed whether I turn it off or on, it still keeps working when I move it. Does the switch at the bottom actually do anything now? Or do I have a defective one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch on the bottom is the on-off switch.  The mouse should not move after you turn it off.  If it still moves after you turn it off, it's possible the switch is defective (assuming you're not also touching a trackpad or have another BT mouse connected at the same time).

[image]

Comment: Yup it looks like it IS defective - still works even with the switch on OFF. Cheers